# How does disarming work? What skills are used?

Tags: disarming, stars-without-number, stars-without-number-revised

I'm playing Stars Without Number revised. There is a section on page 52 that describes "disarming a foe" with an example at the bottom of the page:

> Thus, if a bare-handed assailant tried to rip the gun  out of the hands of an enemy alien, the assailant would  need to hit with a Punch attack and then roll either Str/Punch or Dex/Punch against the alien’s skill check + 3.

But I'm not sure what skill the alien can use. I feel like if were sword fighting we'd both use stab. Does the alien use punch? Shoot doesn't feel right for close combat. Exert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There is no explicit rule, so pick the most relevant skill

Disarming works like this (p. 52, **Disarm a Foe**)

> To execute a disarm, the assailant must choose to
> spend their Main Action doing so and make a successful
> attack roll. If they hit, they do no damage; **instead, both
> they and their targets make Dex or Strength-modified
> skill checks with the weapons they’re using, with the
> defender gaining a +3 bonus on the roll**. If the attacker
> wins the opposed check, the enemy is disarmed. On a
> tie, both are disarmed.

What skills you use is not defined here. The rules for skill checks say (p. 47, Skill Checks)

> To make a skill check, roll 2d6 and **add the most
> relevant skill** level and attribute modifier. [...]
> Some checks might be suitable for more than one skill. A javelin-throwing contest might use Exert for being an athletic contest, or Shoot for involving a ranged weapon, or Stab for using a muscle-powered thrown weapon. **In such cases the PC can use the best applicable skill**.

Weapon related skills are typcially Punch, Stab, or Shoot.

> A PC’s skill level is their Punch, Stab, or Shoot
> skill in most cases, depending on what kind of weapon
> they’re using.

You are right that none of them fits the situation perfectly, but what to do there is up to the DM and you. In the absence of a specific "Grip" skill, you probably allow the character to use the best skill they have related to the weapon, based on the idea that to shoot or stab, you also need to have a firm grip on the weapon, and that will help you against being disarmed.

Another idea could be Exert, but that is out as it says explicitly:

> You can use it as a combat skill when throwing things, though
> it doesn’t qualify as a combat skill for other ends.

Comment: if I'm trying to disarm someone with a sword, stab makes sense. if I'm trying to disarm someone with a gun, shoot doesn't seem to make sense to me. honestly, it seems to me you are both trying to exert (despite the rule being to the contrary)

Comment: @kdubs The RPG police won't slam down your door and bust you for doing it, if you want to do that. I'm just telling you what the rules say. Nothing wrong with modding them if they don't work for you.

Comment: 'cuz snitches get stitches... 8- )  I get what you saying. it's just their example is right up to the point where they don't specify which skill. thanks for you input.